# what is best practice of keeping my code up to data with AWS autoscaling groups?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, jenkins, autoscaling

I am turning my laravel application from being deployed on a single AWS EC2 instance to an autoscaling group, I have created a proper Golden AMI with my code base and webserver configurations and set the scaling policy; everything went well so far.

I am wandering what is the best way to deploy code updates into the target group.

N.B: Currently I am using bitbucket for source control and Jenkins for CI/CD of single EC2 instance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about, but normally you would use CodeDeploy to deploy new versions of your app onto the instances in ASG.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy to existing instances (code deploy as mentioned by Marcin) or userdata to download updates during instance launch and Maximum Instance Lifetime to kill instances that have been up for too long otherwise